# C# and Python result difference - basic Math

Tags: python, c#, math, floor-division

So I have tried the same math in c# and python but got 2 different answer. can someone please explain why is this happening.

```
def test():
l = 50
r = 3
gg= l + (r - l) / 2
mid = l + (r - l) // 2
print(mid)
print(gg)

public void test()
    {
        var l = 50;
        var r = 3;
        var gg = l + (r - l) / 2;

        double x = l + (r - l) / 2;
        var mid = Math.Floor(x);
        Console.WriteLine(mid);
        Console.WriteLine(gg);
    }
```

Comment: can you post the results you're getting in both cases?

Comment: I don't know c# but it probably performs integer division on integers (even when assigned back to a double), when python 3 does not unless "//" is used

Comment: In C# you're dealing with `int` division and that truncates.  In Python it defaults to floating point division that does not truncate.  Try changing your values in C# to end with .0 as in `var l = 50.0;`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I was getting 27 in c# and 26.5 in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C#, the `/` operator performs integer division (ignores the fractional part) when both values are type `int`. For example, 3 / 2 = 1, since the fractional part (0.5) is dropped.

As a result, in your equation, the operation `(r - l) / 2` is evaluating to -23, since `(3 - 50) / 2` = `-47 / 2` = `-23` (again, the fractional part is dropped). Then, `50 + (-23)` = 27.

However, Python does not do this. By default, all division, whether between integers or doubles, is "normal" division - the fractional part is kept. Because of that, the result is the same as you'd get on a calculator: `50 + (3 - 50) / 2` = 26.5

If you want C# to calculate this the same way as Python, the easiest way is to make one of the numbers a double. Adding `.0` to the end of the divisor should do the trick:

```cs
// changed '2' to '2.0'
var gg = l + (r - l) / 2.0;
double x = l + (r - l) / 2.0;
```

> 26
> 26.5